# How can I customise the response of the login in Spring Security Rest

Tags: grails, spring-security-rest

Using Grails 3 and Spring Security Rest, I'm calling the URI `localhost:8080/api/login` to authenticate the user.

The response is:

```
{
    access_token: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1...",
    roles: [...],
    username: "username"
}
```

But I want to customize this response to return the full `User` object. Like this:

```
{
    access_token: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1...",
    roles: [...],
    username: "username",
    fullName: "Full Name",
    mobile: "123345678",
    adress: "...",
    ...
}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

First implement AccessTokenJsonRenderer and register it in resources.groovy.